# KineticJS: How do I scale a Stage?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a KineticJS Stage with one layer. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/7QTmz/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 200,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        width: 106,
        height: 118
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(yoda);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    stage.size({
        width: 100,
        height: 200
    });

    layer.draw();
    stage.draw();
};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

**How can I resize the stage such that stage.toDataUrl() will return an image with the new dimensions?**

Comment: have you looked at `.size()`? http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#size

Comment: @Greg: `stage.size` does not reset the stage's size--it's readonly on the stage object.

Comment: @markE It works, just tested with this line: `stage.size({width: 1366, height: 274})`. Docs seem accurate.

Comment: @Greg, Agreed!  KineticJS docs have always been somewhat misleading.  I haven't tried 5.1...So in 5.1 does resizing the stage also resize the stage content?

Comment: @markE Ah yeah apparently `.size` is now overloaded in 5.1, I didn't have a need to use it in older versions, so not sure what the analogue would be... `.setWidth` and `.setHeight` seperately?

Comment: @Greg, thanks for the info on v5.1! I just tried stage.size({width:newWidth,height:newHeight}); in v5.1 and the stage does report a new size but the container & stage remain visibly 1X.  Theoretically the questioner could stage.size plus resize the container element plus stage.scaleX/stage.scaleY and then stage.toDataURL would produce a 2X image.

Comment: @markE What is the correct way to resize a stage and the content?

Comment: Interesting. For me it is changing visibly as well.  New bug perhaps?

Comment: @Greg. Probably not a bug.  I defensively set the content element's width/height so it's always positioned properly on a webpage.  After I remove the fixed content sizing the stage becomes 2X tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 2X the stage and its content like this (also...thanks to @Greg for info on stage.size):

```
var scaleFactor=2;

stage.size({width:stage.width()*scaleFactor,height:stage.height()*scaleFactor});

stage.scaleX(scaleFactor);
stage.scaleY(scaleFactor);

stage.draw();
```

Comment: Please make the answer more general instead of 2x take e.g., n as scale factor

Comment: Done! I've replaced the fixed "2" with a varialble scale factor.  Cheers!